# What does this error mean, and how do I rectify it?

Tags: c#, decimal

[system.overflow exception: value too small or too large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cvjm.png)

I'm busy with a loan calculator app. In the code below, I'm trying to calculate the loan payment (paymentD; payment) to push into a loan object. The user values which are used to calculate the loan are: Loan Amount (amountD), Loan Rate (monthlyRate;rateD), and Loan Term (term).

In the values mentioned above, the Loan Amount and Loan Rate are decimals, and the term is of type int. As such, I had to convert the decimal type to the double type in order to calculate paymentD, before reconverting the answer back to a decimal (payment).

However when I run the code, it only works when I enter a whole number into the rate value. When I try to use a fraction value (say 3.5), it throws this error. When debugging for the 3.5, payment returns `NaN`.

How do I fix this?
[integer value added to the rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkmqi.png)

Code:

```
private decimal CalcMonthlyPayments(decimal amount, int term, decimal rate)
{
    
    var monthlyRate = CalcMonthlyRate(rate);
    var rateD = Convert.ToDouble(monthlyRate);

    var amountD = Convert.ToDouble(amount);

    var paymentD = (amountD * rateD) / (1 - Math.Pow(1 + rateD, -term));
    var payment = Convert.ToDecimal(paymentD);

    return payment;
}

private decimal CalcMonthlyRate(decimal rate)
{
    return rate / 1200;
}

private decimal CalcMonthlyInterest(decimal balance, decimal monthlyRate)
{
    return balance * monthlyRate;
}
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: What's the value of `PaymentD` when that error is thrown?

Comment: Please upload CODE (text) and not screen shots.  You should should the values of all local variables....(right before) the exception is thrown

Comment: Presumably the value is too large or too small. Check the exact value of paymentD immediately before the return line, e.g. by printing it to the console.

Comment: Why are you converting `decimal` to `double` to do the calculation? `Double` is notorious for its inaccuracy. A multiplication and division can result in an extra 1-to-a-large-negative-exponent, and `decimal` can't represent that. Do your calculations directly with `decimal` instead. The `Convert` methods should be severe red flags whenever you use them.

Comment: Unrelated, I believe your calculation should be using `monthlyRate` variable instead of `rateD`. I don't think it would matter for the problem you are encountering though.

Comment: @madreflection, the math library only works well with doubles...hence I had to convert first.

Comment: As for question formatting, edit your question with the edit button. Then copy and paste your code as text. Highlight what you pasted and click the `{}` button in the editor to preserve line-feeds and white-space.

Comment: Re the Math library, it looks like `Math.Pow` is the only method of concern.  Limit your use of `double` to the inputs and outputs of that call instead of involving other calculations. If you do that and you're still getting `double` values that can't be represented in `decimal`, write your own function to do exponentiation in `decimal`.

Comment: @JNevill, rateD is the converted version of monthlyRate. And paymentD returns NaN. However when I change the rate input to a whole number, the program runs well.

Comment: @SvenViking the debugger returns "NaN".

Comment: @VNgcobo Ah! Thank you for the clarification. I overlooked that in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You have a value that is too big or too small for the data-type being used.

Here is an example (of a different data type) that shows how you can "pre check" on ~some values.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int16.maxvalue?view=net-6.0#examples

But if you have something like this:

```
Int16 result = Int16.MaxValue + 100;
```

you can see the issue.  The code is trying to go 100 "beyond" the supported max.